# Route traffic from interface to real router

Tags: iptables, route, forwarding

I'm trying to capture packets sent from my phone using my raspberry pi, basically a MITM kind of thing.

I have changed my phone's wireless settings to use the raspberry pi's ip address as the router then tried to make changes to the pi's routing table, but I can't get it to work. My phone says it's not connected to the internet and a packet capture shows requests, but they never succeeded.

I've done the following:

```
ifconfig wlan0:1

ifconfig wlan0:1 192.168.0.100 netmask 255.255.255.0

echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

route add default gw 192.168.0.1 wlan0:1
```

I've also added `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1` to `/etc/sysctl.conf`, and ran `sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf`.

Lastly, while googling for an answer I found some examples where they forward one or two ports. If possible, I'd like to forward all traffic.

EDIT:
In response to a comment below...
The router `192.168.0.1` is the AP for my home network. I'm not using the pi as a wireless access point since I'm connecting it to the network using its wireless card.

Comment: Please edit the question and indicate if the RaspPi works as a WLAN access point (AP), and your phone is connected to this AP, or if it is a normal WLAN client, and your router is the AP. In the latter case, ICMP REDIRECT messages may tell your phone to use the router as gateway, and not the RaspPi. Also, doing captures on as many points as possible (phone, RaspPi, router) would help to find out what is going on.

Comment: `wireshark` is a good tool https://www.wireshark.org/

Comment: You can configure at least some RaspPi's as both AP and client, see e.g. [here](https://imti.co/iot-wifi/) (google for more tutorials). Try this, connect your phone to the RaspPi AP, and the RaspPi to the router AP, and see if the problem persists. (Unless you want to do actual debugging of the problem with tcpdump/wireshark).

Comment: After messing with it much more I got it to work, but I don't know how. If I were to guess, it would be because I used a NAT argument when adding routes.

Comment: in response to people... dirkt: thanks for informing me of the ICMP REDIRECT. That got me thinking and led me to my hypothesis that NAT was the solution. I couldn't use the pi as an AP bc the router is next door in the gf's parents' house.

waltinator: I agree! I used wireshark a lot while figuring all this out.